# Blazor Grid component how to install it

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Just found out there is a new `grid` component for `Blazor`; nevertheless, when I tried to use it on my `Razor` page, the markups were not recognized. Should I install additional `packages` from nuget or? Where exactly is it?

```
<div class = "InventoryGrid">
<Grid Items="@forecasts" ItemSize="35" Virtualize="true">
    <PropertyColumn Title="Date" Property="@(x=>x.Date)" />"
</Grid>
</div>
```

Comment: Blazor does not have a built-in component 'Grid'

Comment: Are you referring to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/ui/grid-layout

Comment: News to me.  I've just checked the Repo and the only `Grid` is a razor component used for benchmark testing https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/benchmarkapps/Wasm.Performance/TestApp/Shared/FastGrid/Grid.razor

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kesUNeBZ1Os 9:01

Answer (score 1):

The Grid component you are referring to is project code in Steve Sanderson's BlazeOrbital presentation solution.  You can find it [here](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazeOrbital/blob/main/BlazeOrbital/QuickGrid/Grid.razor).

It's not part of Blazor in Net6.

Comment: Is there any official grid as the one by Sanderson, or is it fine just to use the Sanderson one on production envinorment, what u think?

Comment: I'd just lift Steve's code and use/adapt it to my needs.  I have my own 5.0 version you can see here for example https://cec-blazor-database.azurewebsites.net/fetchdata. but it's bound into my other UI components.

Answer (score 0):

I very strongly recommend making your own `<ArieGrid>` component that takes in table data as a `Parameter`.  In `<ArieGrid>`, for each row of data, you have an `<ArieGridRow>` component that takes a row of data.  In `<ArieGridRow>`, for each data cell, you have an `<ArieGridCell>` component that takes in a single data item.

It seems to me that doing this yourself would likely be faster than trying to figure out how somebody else's  component works.

Comment: ya, but when we talked about ordering, paginations, virtuial grid etc it become bigger work to do which i do not really have so much time. I thought there is smth out of the box i can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the RadZen datagrid component here - https://blazor.radzen.com/datagrid. I found this quite easy to integrate.

Comment: but it's not free not?

Comment: Radzen Blazor Components are open source and free for commercial use. Paid support is available.